# How to make a plane perpendicular to the x axis with plotly js

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I am using the plotly javascript library and I am trying to draw a plane perpendicular to the x axis. All I can do right now is a plane perpendicular to the z axis here : https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-leavitt-hktz3

with this code:

```
surface = {
    type: "surface",
    z: [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],
    opacity: 0.7,
    colorscale: "Greys",
    showscale: false,
    name: "Plane of Best Fit"
  };
```

I see many examples with the R or python library of plotly but not with javascript.
Can somebody help me do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I achieved to draw a plane perpendicular to the x axis by putting the coordinates like this:

```
z:[[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
    [0. , 0.5, 1. ]]
y:[[0.,  0.,  0.],
    [1.,  1.,  1.]]
x:[[0.,  0.,  0.],
    [0,  0,  0]]
```

I followed the example in python here: https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2017/12/draw-continuous-electric-field-lines-3d-plotly.html